# WPF textbox text databinding strange behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

Assume I have with texbox and textblock:

```
    <TextBox Name="textBox1"
             Text="{Binding Path=user,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1},
                            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" 
               Text="{Binding Path=user, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1},
                            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Code behind:

```
    private string _user = "a";

    public string user
    {
        get
        {
            return _user;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim()))
                _user = value;
            //else
                //_user = _user + Environment.NewLine;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("user");

        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve - is not allow user to enter empty string (or whitespace) in textbox and textblock. If text is empty - i simply restore previous value (cleared by user text - "a" in case of my code).

Code above works perfectly for textblock, but not for textbox (screenshot after pressing backspace inside textbox):

[image]

Moreover if you remove comment from

```
 //else
       //_user = _user + Environment.NewLine;
```

everything works like a charm (exept for I need to restore previous value, not value with Environment.NewLine :) of course)

So what's happening? Why behavior of textbox differs much from expected (and even differs from textblock behavior)?

**UPDATE:**

**What I'm expecting:**

If I press backspace in textbox my expression `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim())` is false.

`_user` is not updated (it is still "a").

Calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("user")` on the next line should force binding to get "a" (and `_user` equals "a" as expected if I touggle breakpoint in getter).

But as you can see on a screenshot - textbox is empty for some reason.

Comment: Whats with the weird RelativeSource binding - I think you can completely remove that you do not need to specify a source - the DataContext is automatically the Window itself.

Comment: I cannot see the problem - if you press backspace in textbox your expression: `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim())` will be false so _user will not be updated so when the binding gets it again it will still be "a"!

Comment: You cannot type in  `TextBlock` so how can you update its value - it will never call set!

Comment: @markmnl If I press backspace in textbox my expression: `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim())` is false. _user is not updated (it is still "a"). Calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("user")` on the next line should force binding to get "a" (and it is so if I touggle breakpoint in setter). But as you can see on a screenshot - textbox is empty for some reason. I've updated my question.

Comment: @markmnl My misprint - if I touggle breakpoint in **getter** of course.

Comment: @markmnl Removing `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}` makes binding not working for me. Don't know why but **DataContext is automatically the Window itself** is not correct statement in my case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48663/discussion-between-bairog-and-markmnl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call that a bug of any kind. The difference is caused because the `TextBox` can be changed from two places, whereas the `TextBlock` can only be changed from one. That one source has a rule that won't allow the value to be an empty `string` and so, it won't show an empty `string`. The `TextBox` on the other hand has no such rule to stop the user from changing the value. For that, you'd need to add a handler to the `TextBox.PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path=user, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    AncestorType=my:MainWindow}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

...

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim().Length == 1 && 
        (e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back)) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Also note that you didn't need to set half of those properties in your `RelativeSource Binding`... the above should work just the same. The `TextBox.TextProperty DependencyProperty` has the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag set in its default `FrameworkMetadata`, so you don't need to use `Mode=TwoWay` here and you only need to set the `AncestorType` property.

Comment: The TextBlock honors the NotifyPropertyChanged and the get and the TextBox does not - that is a bug. And that bug is not present in .NET 4.5.  Even in 3.5 you can reset "aa" to "bb" and it works.

Comment: Either way, adding a handler to the `TextBox.PreviewKeyDown` event can do what the user wants.

Comment: Attaching a handler to the `TextBox.PreviewKeyDown` saves the problem for me. I'm accepting this one, thx. But despite of that I still rate this **TextBox** behavior as unexpected and strange. For me it's rather a bug (sorry, I can't test is on **.NET 4.5** as @Blam suggested)

Comment: And +1 for pointing me on that redundant properties :) BTW `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}` was automatically set by VS 2010 SP1 - I was chosing binding type with my mouse. Strange IDE behavior..

Comment: I didn't get your first paragraph explanation. `NotifyPropertyChanged("user")` should trigger the binding and re-set the `TextBox`'s `TextProperty` to the last character, shouldn't it ? Also, your answer does not prevent the user from selecting and deleting text, or right click -> cut, etc. Anyways, the orginal question is based on a dubious requirement.

Comment: @franssu, apparently the `TextBox` *is* supposed to do that, but it never has (in .NET 4)... doesn't seem to be much of a problem to me. As for not implementing code to stop the CUT function... I had to leave something for the question author to do, didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem
When people told me they could not reproduce it led me to think environment
For me it does not work on .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0 but it does work on .NET 4.5
The answer is try it on .NET 4.5

This is a XAML way to set DataContext
No reason for TwoWay or UpdateSourceTrigger on a TextBlock

```
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextNoEmpty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextNoEmpty, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Tested the above on .NET 3.5 and it reproduced the problem
Tested the above on .NET 4.5 and it worked properly

Would probably have same problem if you tried to truncate to a maximum length in the setter.

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?   That is tested code that reproduced the problem on 3.5 and worked on 4.5.

Comment: That's not the answer to his question, the datacontext's "problem" was not his original question..

Comment: His question is : why, since my setter refuses to set the value, does the TextBox's text change ?

Comment: And (unlike you) I did answer the question. The answer is that it works on .NET 4.5.  See the third sentence.

Comment: Sorry, but it's confusing you mention the problem about the DataContext while you might still be able to reproduce the problem using a binding with `{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}`

Comment: @franssu I did not say the problem was with the DataContext I said that is a XAML way to set DataContext.  Since many of the comments got side tracked on DataContext I felt it added value.

Comment: @Blam, I'd agree that there's no need to set `Mode=TwoWay` on a `TextBox.Text` property, but I'm curious why you think that there's no need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property... care to enlighten me?

Comment: @Sheridan "UpdateSource".  A read only item does not not update source.  Test.

Comment: What is read only here? This question doesn't mention read only.

Comment: @Sheridan A TextBlock is read only.  What part of a read only UI element could never update to a source in not clear?  Refer to the documentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahhhh, somehow I missed the *on a TextBlock* part of *No reason for TwoWay or UpdateSourceTrigger on a TextBlock*... not sure how, but apologies.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm restricted to **.NET 4.0 only**. So your I can't test your solution

Comment: Go 4.5 when you get a chance.  It fixed a couple quirky items for me.

Comment: @Blam Thx, I'll switch to **.NET 4.5** ASAP